# Rename multiple files in a directory with single bash command

Tags: bash

I'm trying to rename multiple files in a directory. The intention is to remove the trailing _bkp extension.
What I've come up with is as shown below, but as you all know, this wont work, but you get the idea. Any help??

```
find -iname "*.sql_bkp" -exec mv {} sed -e 's/\_bkp//g' {} \;
```

or

```
find -iname *.sql_bkp -exec mv {} $(sed -e 's/\_bkp//g' {}) \;
```

Comment: don't you have to give a directory to find?

Comment: @123 GNU find assumes `.` if you don't specify one

Comment: @EricRenouf Ah right, didn't know that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
find . -iname '*.sql_bkp' -exec bash -c 'echo mv "$1" "${1%_bkp}"' - {} \;
```

When you're satisfied with the output, just remove `echo` before `mv`

Comment: `"${1%_bkp}"` removed `_bkp` from end of `$1`. `- {}` passes 2 arguments to `bash -c` command lines.Dummy argument `-` populated `$0` and `{}` populates `$1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$find -iname "*.sql_bkp" -exec basename {} _bkp \;
```

OR

```
$for i in *.sql_bkp; do mv "$i" "$(basename "$i" _bkp)";done
```